# How to convert json from url into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, url, python-requests

with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.loves.com/api/sitecore/StoreSearch/SearchStores'

#get the data from url
response = requests.get(url).json()

df = pd.read_json(url)

df1 = pd.json_normalize(response)
```

both DFs return this:
[image]

This is what the response looks like
[image]

How to get normal pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.loves.com/api/sitecore/StoreSearch/SearchStores'

#get the data from url
response = requests.get(url).json()

df1 = pd.json_normalize(response, record_path=['Points'])
```

Comment: Added https://www.loves.com/api/sitecore/StoreSearch/SearchStores

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer, this made the trick

```
df1 = pd.json_normalize(response, record_path=['Points'])
```